# Show only entries from database which are older than two months

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have unix timestamps in my database. Now I want to get only results, which are two months old.

This won't work, because it shows entries which are older than two months.

```
$unixbefore2months = strtotime('-2 month');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE time > "'.$unixbefore2months.'"';
```

So I have the timestamps which determines the the time two months ago (from now) and the entries in the database with their creation time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to convert them, and it can be done without any PHP variables if you use the native MySQL `DATE_SUB()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH));
```

See the [MySQL date & time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) reference for details on `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and `DATE_SUB()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's time to learn some *debugging*.

Asking this kind of questions on is quite useless thing.
The only person who can help you actually is yourself.

So, you have to learn some tricks.

1. Always verify your variables.
   What does unixbefore2months contain? You have to idea. Verify it: `echo date("Y-m-d",unixbefore2months);`
   What does $query contain? You have to idea. Verify it: `echo $query;` Run this query in the console.
2. Verify your data.
   What is the field type? What does `desc table` query say?
   Do you have any timestamps in the table?
   What are they?

Look, nobody can answer these questions but you. Yet armed with answers you will spot the problem easily

Comment: `echo $unixbefore2months;` gives 1323272062. `echo date("Y-m-d",$unixbefore2months);` gives 2011-12-07. `echo $query;` gives `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE time > 1323272062`. time is a varchar(50) and it contains strings like `1302689069`. I have verified everything before except of `$query`. I thought I make a mistake when comparing strings ... But now it seems to work. Don't know what I changed.

Comment: well, it happens too. anyway you have to store unix timestamps in the INT field, not varchar.

Comment: Can you explain the difference? Why is INT better? Is it because it can store more values?

Comment: isn't it obvious? 1302689069 is an integer and mysql has a field type exactly for this. Why not to use it?